# How do I add prisoners in Prison Architect?

Tags: prison-architect

I did not tick fog of war and add prisoners forever. I have cells, kitchen, office, canteen, yard. How do I add prisoners?

Comment: Do you have real cells or only a holding cell? In the latest version, the holding cell does not count toward your prison capacity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need functional (working toilet and bed) cells. If you did not opt for the steady flow of prisoners, you will only receive new prisoners when you have empty cells. Also, make sure that your cell areas say "CELL", not "SOLITARY" or "HOLDING CELL"

Answer (score 2):

If you have all the required materials in your cell (toilet,bed,cell door) and they still don't go into the cell you need to escort them into the cell (left click the prisoner and right click in the cell you want to move the prisoner to).

Answer (score 2):

In the most recent version, you have to select if you want to receive new prisoners (option is called "open" and "closed" I think), also what kind of prisoners (min, normal, max security). by default, you will only receive normal security prisoners. But you will receive prisoners, even if there are no cells for them yet.

This setting has to be made in the prisoners tab in the journal (i think this was the correct tab.)

Answer (score 0):

Just make cells with water and electricity then wait a bit until they come